# What does cache actually cache in RMarkdown? Errors in attachment

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have just started testing Rmarkdown for use in creating a codebook of a dataset, and I am quite puzzled by its behaviour when using `cache = TRUE`. I'm running it on using RStudio 1.1.463. rmarkdown_1.11, knitr_1.21 and the tidyverse_1.2.1.

Take the following sample code which includes some doc and chunk options  I'm interested in, attaches all libraries I normally use (noting that I've added "|" in a couple of places for appropriate formatting on SO):

````
---
title: "Test"
date: 2019-03-11
output: 
  html_document
---
  
  
```{r header, echo= FALSE, include=FALSE, cache = TRUE, warning= FALSE}

attach(mtcars)

library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(summarytools)

opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, error = TRUE)

|```

# mtcars dataset heading

## map of car purchases

## cyl variable

```{r} 

kable(descr(cyl))

|```
````

When I hit the Knit button on RStudio for the first time (without an existing cache folder), the results are as expected. If I hit Knit again, the following happens:

- `cyl` is not found
- `kable`, `descr` both throw 'could not find function' errors

If the parent packages/dataframes are called explicitly, these problems disappear. If `cache = FALSE` there are no issues.

Why would `cache = TRUE` trigger this behaviour? For this codebook, I thought of attaching the final dataset and then present some summaries for each variable. I would also like to generate a couple of `sf` maps with many of the variables. I thought of processing everything in such a header chunk, and then call on various bits throughout the document. Should I think differently?

Incidentally, I don't quite understand why it is necessary to explicitly `library(knitr)` on an Rmarkdown document as I thought it was a key package to 'knit' the document... If I remove it, `opts_chunk` is not found.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `cache = TRUE` tries to cache the R objects created in a chunk.  Your first chunk does a lot more than just create objects:  the `attach` and `require` calls each have side effects:  modifying the search list, loading packages, etc.   Those side effects aren't cached, but they are needed for your document to work:  since `knitr` sees no reason to run the chunk again your document fails on the second run.

You normally use `cache = TRUE` when the chunk does a long slow computation to produce a dataset for later plotting or summarizing, because then subsequent runs can skip the slow part of the computation.

You ask why `require(knitr)` is needed.  Strictly speaking, it's not needed: you could have used `knitr::opts_chunk` instead.  But more to the point, the idea is that an R Markdown document is a description of a standalone R session.  Yes, you need `knitr` to process it, but it should give the same results as if you just ran the code on its own in an empty session.  (This isn't exactly true:  `knitr`'s chunk options and hooks modify the behaviour a bit, but it's a convenient mental model of what's going on.)

Comment: Thanks user2554330! I understand that `cache` was intended to store objects and avoid repeated computation... That makes sense. But why should that make the attachments not work the second time around?

Comment: If you cache that first chunk, it won't be executed the second time around, so none of the necessary side effects will happen.  I've edited the answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are not time-consuming.
I usually pull apart libraries and setup from data in two differents chunks, and the last one set `cache=TRUE`.